# How do the Canon 5DS R and 5D Mark III compare in dynamic range?

Tags: canon, dynamic-range

Canon 5DS R vs 5D Mark III (current camera) — Is the dynamic range the same? Should I move to a Sony sensor? More megapixels is good, but Sony sensors (Sony A7R II/Nikon D810/Pentax 645Z) have bigger/better dynamic range, as far as I could read.

I had problems with banding, chroma noise, etc. in the past with my 5D Mark II and 5D Mark III RAW files.

Comment: Dynamic range - as defined how? And measured by whom?

Comment: At what ISO ranges? Using what kind of testing methodologies?

Answer (score 2):

The general rule is that larger pixels can capture greater dynamic-range. This of course would be a disadvantage for the 5DS R expect that technology has improved. Despite the smaller pixels which can hold fewer photons, there is less noise in the circuitry within the 5DS[R] sensor. The result is a greater dynamic range by slightly more than half a stop.

Should you want even more dynamic-range from a single shot, you can by getting the [Nikon D610](http://www.neocamera.com/camera/nikon/d610/review) which offers a full 2 stops more than either 5DS or 5DS R at base ISO. There are other DSLRs to attain similar dynamic-range, namely the Nikon D810, D800 and D750. For high ISO, I found that the [Nikon D4S](http://www.neocamera.com/camera/nikon/d4s/review) had the widest dynamic-range.

You mention Sony which unfortunately I have not reviewed yet, so I cannot tell if the dynamic-range is comparable but we do know that Sony and Nikon share sensors which indicates they should be close in terms of RAW performance. You may check with [DxOMark](http://www.dxomark.com/best-cameras-for-landscape) which measures dynamic-range and other metrics independently from manufacturers, although I find them inconsistent with my results in the last two years.

Answer (score 0):

While most reviews I've seen ding the 5Ds (and 5Dsr) for it's relatively low Dynamic Range (compared to competitors), several measurements/estimates I found available at different sites showed a slight improvement over the 5D mark iii, e.g.:

- http://www.imaging-resource.com/cameras/canon/5d-mark-iii/vs/canon/5ds-r/
- http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/canon-eos-5ds-sr/11

As you've noticed, the consensus seems to be that current Canon sensors lag behind Sony and Nikon in terms of Dynamic Range (and often low ISO performance).

I haven't shot any of these (5D, Sony Nikon) so I can't tell you from experience but that's what I keep reading in reviews and such.

But Canon has really cool lenses :-)